# PDO-exception for deleting not existing row

Tags: php, sql, pdo

In my table

```
id |name
1  | one
```

then

```
$id = '2';
$sql=$this-con->query("delete from  aTable WHERE id = '".$id."' " );
```

the line will just execute with

```
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 0.000 sec. */
```

Even there's is no such id `2` in the table .

How could I manage to prevent this with `PHP` or maybe `SQL`.
because in my PHP i need to tell the user that there is no such row, but how to catch that missing row without checking it first trough custom code.Because :

```
 if($sql){
// Tell user the row is deleted, but (in fact there is no such row with the id in the column)

        }

     else{
      // there must be exception goes here
      }
```

You get what I mean ? or There is no such way without custom checking first?

Comment: You should start using prepared statements

Comment: @DarkBee, yes i'm using that, it's just a short-fast snippet I create to explain my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PDO::exec()` returns the number of rows that were modified or deleted by the SQL statement you issued. If no rows were affected, `PDO::exec()` returns 0.

try this:

> $nrows = $this-con->query("delete from  aTable WHERE id =
>   "'".$id."'")->fetchColumn();

Answer (score 2):

Are you using PDO or a pure MySQL functions in PHP?

With a PDO you can use prepared statement and then get the rowCount like so:

```
$st = $conn->prepare("delete from  aTable WHERE id = '".$id."' " );
$st->execute();

if($st->rowCount()) {
    // return the number of affected rows: Record deleted
} else {
    // no such record in the database
}
```

If you are using pure MySQL functions (and you really should NOT be using them) then go with the mysql_affected_rows():

```
$result = mysql_query("delete from  aTable WHERE id = '".$id."' ");
if(mysql_affected_rows()) {
    // record found and deleted
} else {
    // no such record in the database
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `If you are using pure MySQL functions (and you really should NOT be using them)` ?

Comment: @NatNaydenova, If you're going to use a prepared statement, which you should, then you should be using a parameter for the $id value to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: @MarkLeiber You're absolutely correct, but I decided to leave it out of the scope of the question

Comment: @febri23 Well, the way you are using query() in your code - you are not securing it in any way and are vulnerable to SQL injections. With PDO and prepared statements you are pretty much letting the database server decide how to secure the requests. http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: @NatNaydenova like I said before at my comment above, this is just a "short-fast snippet" to make the question clear & avoid verbose words, there's nothing to do with security , plus prepare-statement of PDO is not the only way to secure SQL injection.

Comment: but +1 for contributing anyway.